# "afcl" namespace missing in ArrayFire 3.7.2

Tags: arrayfire

In the [official docs](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__opencl__mat.htm#ga1984398db67a52977435e653bb842da7) there are functions like afcl::getContext. But when I `#include <arrayfire.h>`, I don't get access to any afcl namespace. How do I access such functions?

Answer (score 1):

The needed #include is:

```
#include <af/opencl.h>
```

([source](http://arrayfire.org/docs/interop_opencl.htm))